# Quickest mate with Queens exchange

Tags: optimization, chess, construction

If both players cooperate, what is the quickest mate in chess that includes a Queens exchange, in a legal game?

Comment: What's the exact definition of a "Queens exchange"?

Comment: @DrXorile "both queens get taken" is the only definition I can think of. That's the usual meaning, at least.

Comment: @DrXorile more precisely, both queens are captured on consecutive moves.

Comment: @DanielMathias Why consecutive? There are many cases in actual chess games where you might take a tempo, e.g. to check, before taking a hanging queen.

Comment: @brianpck Good point. Of course, my intent was to exclude unrelated queen captures.

Comment: This is exactly why I asked!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Black can mate in

> 5

moves

> 1.b3 a5 (h5 also works) 2.Ba3 Ra6 3.Qc1 Rc6 4.Bxe7 Rxc2 5.Bxd8 Rxc1#

Animation:

> [image: animation]

Old answer:

Two more in

> 5 1/2

> 1.e4 e5 2.d4 f5 3.Qh5+ g6 4.Be2 Qg5 5.Bxg5 gxh5 6.Bxh5#

and

> 1.Nc3 e5 2.d4 exd4 3.Bg5 dxc3 4.Qxd7+ N or B or Q or Kxd7 5.Rd1 N or B or Q or K moves back to where they came from 6. Rxd8#

Comment: Would we say that's a "Queen Exchange"?

Comment: I would not consider the new solution to have a queen exchange. The queens must be captured on consecutive moves, otherwise they are independent losses.

Comment: That's a rather narrow view, though I can see how it is tricky to come up with a more flexible definition in a cooperative setting. Anyway, it's easy enough to fix ...

Comment: Agreed. As pointed out in comment above, it isn't strictly necessary for the captures to be on consecutive moves. In any case, your revision certainly qualifies.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if this is the quickest way, but here's a mate in 6:

> 1. c4 c5 2. Nc3 Nc6 3. Qb3 Qb6 4. Qxb6 axb6 5. Nb5 Nd8 6. Nc7# 1-0